# Calling a generic function in swift

Tags: swift

I have the following struct, variable and a function:

```
struct MyModel {
    var keyString: String
    var keyNum: Int
}

let data = "{\"keyString\": \"valueString\", \"keyNum\": 1 }"

func myFunction<T: AnyObject>(str: String) throws -> T? {
    return nil
}
```

How can I call the function with MyModel? Below code makes the compiler complain: "Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred"

```
let myModel = try? myFunction(str: data) as? MyModel
```

Link to Swift REPL: http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/57f1fa479ce3c95fc38e63b3

Comment: BTW, calling `mapStringToModel<MyModel>(str: str)` causes: "Cannot explicitly specialize a generic function"

Comment: Why I get down-voted??

Comment: Please don't include the answer in your question. If an answer solved your issue, mark the answer as accepted; you can also post your own answer if you resolved your problem yourself. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your generic type parameter is declared with a constraint, like this:

```
func myFunction<T: AnyObject>
```

So whatever type you use, it must be a reference type or implement `NSObjectProtocol` or something like that.

A swift struct is a value type, so `MyModel` can't possibly be used as a generic type parameter.

Solutions:

- Change the generic type constraint to `<T: Any>` to make it accept value types.
- Remove the generic type constraint.
- Change the struct to a class and add an initializer.

Comment: I have tried to `<T: Any>` but still I get the same error when I call `try? mapStringToModel(str: str) as? MyModel`

Comment: @nacho4d Oops I forgot about that. The type returned by `try? mapStringToModel(str: str) ` is `MyModel??`. You need to unwrap the optional twice.

Comment: Okay... I got it. I wish there was an easier way to get this done. 
This is what my final code: 
http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/57f20291b1e4a3065dde0213